# Set the cursor position at the beginning of a selected text in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a long text in a textbox which is selected. The cursor is at the end of the text. Because of the length of the text i can't see the beginning which is imported. I tried everything SelectAll, Select(start,length), etc but the cursor is or at the end or nothing is selected.

Comment: Can you show some example code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Is this WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF? Please add the appropriate tag

Comment: try using a multiline textbox if you want to see more of the long text.  All you should have to do to set the cursor position is set the .selectionStart property to 0.

Answer (score 2):

If setting focus to the textbox is okay, you can use `SendKeys to select the text with the beginning shown:

```
TextBox1.Focus()
TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
SendKeys.Send("+{HOME}")
```

Comment: Works nicely with wild comboboxes :D

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming WinForms) - You should just be able to do the following:

```
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
    TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
```

Then set the focus on the textbox to see the caret:

```
    TextBox1.Focus()
```

Comment: But... you lose the selection